Is there a smarter way to calculate $F(\omega^{15} + 7)$? (Ordinal arithmetic)
Given the function $F : \text{Ord} \to \text{Ord}$ definite by transfinite recursion as it follows:
$$F(0) = 0 \qquad F(\alpha + 1) = F(\alpha) + \alpha \cdot 2 + 1 \qquad F(\lambda) = \sup_{\gamma < \lambda} F(\gamma)$$
where $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, is there an efficient way to evaluate $F(\omega^{15} + 7)?$
Obviously $F(\omega^{15} + 7) = F(\omega^{15}) + \omega^{15} \cdot 14 + 7$, so the troubles come with $F(\omega^{15})$.
I think it's clear that the intended way is to find and prove a formula for $F(\omega^n)$.
And so I started bashing and found out (by cases/inductions/supremums) the followings:
(There may be errors in the calclulations!)

$F(\omega) = \omega$
$F(\omega + n) = \omega \cdot (2n + 1) + n$
$F(\omega \cdot 2) = \sup_{n \in \omega} (\omega \cdot (2n + 1) + n) = \omega^2$
$F(\omega \cdot 2 + n) = \omega^2 + \omega \cdot 4n + n$
$F(\omega \cdot 3) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^2 + \omega \cdot 4n + n) = \omega^2 \cdot 2$
$F(\omega \cdot 3 + n) = \omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega \cdot 6n + n$
$F(\omega \cdot 4) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega \cdot 6n + n) = \omega^2 \cdot 3$
$F(\omega \cdot n) = \omega^2 \cdot (n-1) \; \forall n > 1$
$F(\omega^2) = \sup_{n > 1} (\omega^2 \cdot (n-1)) = \omega^{3}$
$F(\omega^2 +n) = \omega^3 + \omega^2 \cdot 2n + n$
$F(\omega^2 + \omega) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^3 + \omega^2 \cdot 2n + n) = \omega^3 \cdot 2$
$F(\omega^2 + \omega + n) = \omega^3 \cdot 2 + \omega^2 \cdot 2n + \omega + n$
$F(\omega^2 + \omega \cdot 2) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^3 \cdot 2 + \omega^2 \cdot 2n + \omega + n) = \omega^3 \cdot 3$
$F(\omega^2 + \omega \cdot n) = \omega^3 \cdot (n + 1)$
$F(\omega^2 \cdot 2) = \sup_{n \in \omega} F(\omega^2 + \omega \cdot n) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^3 \cdot (n + 1)) = \omega^4$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + n) = \omega^4 + \omega^2 \cdot 4n + n$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^4 + \omega^2 \cdot 4n + n) = \omega^4 + \omega^3$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega + n) = \omega^4 + \omega^3 + \omega^2 \cdot 4n + \omega + n$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega\cdot 2) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^4 + \omega^3 + \omega^2 \cdot 4n + \omega + n) = \omega^4 + \omega^3 \cdot 2$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega\cdot 2 + n) = \omega^4 + \omega^3 \cdot 2 + \omega^2 \cdot 4n + \omega \cdot 2 + n$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega\cdot 3) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^4 + \omega^3 \cdot 2 + \omega^2 \cdot 4n + \omega \cdot 2 + n) = \omega^4 + \omega^3 \cdot 3$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega\cdot n) = \omega^4 + \omega^3 \cdot n$
$F(\omega^2\cdot 3) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(F(\omega^2\cdot 2 + \omega\cdot n)) = \sup_{n \in \omega}(\omega^4 + \omega^3 \cdot n) = \omega^4 \cdot 2$
$F(\omega^2\cdot n) = \omega^4 \cdot (n-1) \; \forall n > 1$
$F(\omega^3) = \sup_{n > 1}(\omega^4 \cdot (n-1)) = \omega^5$

Now I can't see any pattern between $F(\omega^2)$ and $F(\omega^3)$, and I don't think it's worth continuing further, so I may be on the wrong path. Any suggestion/better idea (possibly avoiding so many calculations)?
Edit 1.: I made again the calculations and apparently something changed above, the likely claim should be: $F(\omega^n) = \omega^{2n-1}$ and the induction should work like:
Inductive hypothesis: $F(\omega^n) = \omega^{2n-1}$ 
Claim: $F(\omega^{n+1}) = \omega^{2(n+1)-1} = \omega^{2n+1}$
Proof: \begin{align} F(\omega^{n+1}) &= F\left(\sup_{m \in \omega} \omega^n \cdot m\right) \\\\ &=\sup_{m \in \omega}F(\omega^n \cdot m) &&(\text{since $F$ is continuous}) \\\\ &=\sup_{m \in \omega}(\omega^{2n} \cdot (m-1)) &&(\star) \\\\ &= \omega^{2n} \cdot \sup_{m > 1} (m - 1) = \omega^{2n + 1}\end{align}
Where $(\star)$ needs to be proved (I think by another induction which uses the inductive hypothesis of the first one (?)). Once fixed the last thing and double-checked everything else the final result should be: $F(\omega^{15} + 7) = \boxed{\omega^{29} + \omega^{15} \cdot 14 + 7}$. I honestly don't know if I've abused of any rules or if this is the most efficient way to solve the problem (if the result it's actually correct).
Edit 2.: Looking more closely at the definition of $F$ in the case of a successor ordinal the recursive formula seems to remember some sort of square of a binomial. So I have further reason to believe that the claim is correct and, maybe, it'd have been enough to calculate up until $F(\omega^2)$ to get the same claim.

@spaceisdarkgreen thx, I will recheck the calculations

Your (edited) post seems correct to me. Anyway, you could have avoided the first bunch of computations by considering only subsequences of limit ordinals. Here is how.
First things first, let's recall that every ordinal may be written as the sum of limit ordinal and a finite ordinal, i.e. $\alpha = \lambda + n$, where $n < \omega$. Now, let's consider a limit ordinal $\lambda$. Then, the recursive relation implies :
$$
F(\alpha + 1) = F(\lambda + n + 1) = F(\lambda + n) + (\lambda + n)\cdot2 + 1 = F(\lambda + n) + \lambda \cdot 2 + n + 1
$$
and finally $F(\lambda + n) = F(\lambda) + \lambda \cdot 2n + n$. In consequence, the value associated to the next limit ordinal, denoted here by $\lambda^+$, is given by
$$
F(\lambda^+) = \sup_{n<\omega} \left(F(\lambda) + \lambda \cdot 2n + n\right). \tag{$*$}
$$
The first step is given by
$$
F(\omega) = \sup_{n<\omega} \left(F(0) + 0 \cdot 2n + n\right) = \sup_{n<\omega} n = \omega
$$
Then, when $\lambda \ge \omega$, the above formula is simplified to
$$
F(\lambda + \omega) =  F(\lambda) + \sup_{n<\omega} (\lambda \cdot 2n + n) = F(\lambda) + \lambda\omega,
$$
hence $F(\lambda + \omega \cdot n) = F(\lambda) + \lambda\omega \cdot n$ by recursion. The next "step" is given by
$$
F(\lambda + \omega^2) = \sup_{n<\omega} F(\lambda + \omega \cdot n) = F(\lambda) + \sup_{n<\omega} \lambda\omega \cdot n = F(\lambda) + \lambda\omega^2,
$$
when $\lambda \ge \omega^2$. It leads to $F(\lambda + \omega^2 \cdot n) = F(\lambda) + \lambda\omega^2 \cdot n$ by recursion again, hence
$$
F(\lambda + \omega^3) = \sup_{n<\omega} F(\lambda + \omega^2 \cdot n) = F(\lambda) + \lambda\omega^3.
$$
You see the emerging pattern, i.e. $F(\lambda + \omega^n) = F(\lambda) + \lambda\omega^n$ for limit ordinals $\lambda \ge \omega^n$. After computing the first terms of the form $\lambda_k = \omega^k$, we understands that $F(\omega^{n+1}) = \omega^{2n+1}$ $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$, which the claim in your edit.

Very nice, thanks!
